# How can I properly upload too long messages as a file?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was doing some research on Discord's capabilities today, and then I noticed that the "upload as file" option is given when a message is more than 2000 characters long.
*The number plays a role here, but my statement can also be wrong, the fact is that some things are posted only as a link and or then not sent at all if I raise `>2000`.*

**Here now the problem:**

I am requesting data from Genius for a lyrics command. I already have some kind of override built in for when `len(data["lyrics"])` is greater than `2000` "characters", that should be Discord's limit after all, otherwise the bot wouldn't be able to process the embed I am trying to send.

How can I manage that lyrics `>2000` are sent as a file?

**Relevant code:**

```py
if len(data["lyrics"]) > 2000:
    return await ctx.send(f"<{data['links']['genius']}>"))
```

- This is the normal request, it works too, but it just throws out the link.
  I then tried to send this via `discord.File` with the corresponding piece of code above, does not work. *(Something like `file=discord.File(data)` was tried too!)*
- Something like `ctx.file.send` does not work in this case either

**The following posts were viewed:**

- [Uploading a file in a embed discord.py (not a image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65596045/uploading-a-file-in-a-embed-discord-py-not-a-image)
- [Discord.py - Sending a text file on DM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62591430/discord-py-sending-a-text-file-on-dm)
- [Discord.py Bot sending file to Discord Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860397/discord-py-bot-sending-file-to-discord-channel)
- [Python discord.py ways to split output to bypass 2000 character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62878525/python-discord-py-ways-to-split-output-to-bypass-2000-character-limit)

**What I want my bot to do if `data["lyrics"] > 2000`:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the text into a `io.StringIO` buffer and pass that into the `discord.File` constructor:

```py
from io import StringIO

text = data["lyrics"]
if len(text) > 2000:
    buffer = StringIO(text)
    f = discord.File(buffer, filename="lyrics.txt")
    await ctx.send(file=f)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I can work with that. At the end I could have also split the embeds, but this is a short and sweet solution, did not know about StringIO to be honest, thanks!